# Jump outside environment in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

Is there a shortcut to leave the current environment and put the cursor after `\end{<environment name>}` in TeXstudio?

```
\begin{<environment name>}
  ...<cursor here>...
\end{<environment name>}
```

*magic*

```
\begin{<environment name>}
  ...
\end{<environment name>}
<cursor here>
```

Comment: I don't suspect there's such a shortcut, but for clarity: do you mean `@\end{environment}` or `\end{environment}@`? (Or even `\end{environment}\n@`?)

Comment: \end{environment}\n@ would be best, but \end{environment}@ works too.

Comment: I've made an edit to the question that I hope best describes what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no builtin function for this, however you could write a macro script for it (`Macros -> Edit Macros`).

This is a basic example script:

```
%SCRIPT
while (!cursor.atEnd()) {
    cursor.movePosition(1, cursorEnums.EndOfLine, cursorEnums.KeepAnchor)
    lineText = cursor.selectedText()
    if (lineText.indexOf("\\end{") >= 0) {
        break
    }
    cursor.movePosition(1, cursorEnums.NextLine)
}
cursor.movePosition(1, cursorEnums.NextLine)
```

You may want to refine it further to handle edge cases like cusor within the `\\end` statement, `\\end` is not the only command on the line etc.

For more information on scripting see the [user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33) and the [examples in the wiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Scripts/).